# Cocos2d-x cross platform development

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, cocos2d-x, windows-phone-8

I want to make a game with my friends on iOs, Android, WP operating systems. We decided to use a cocos2d-x and develop the core of the game on C++. What will be the right way of developing so that we can write the game all together simultaneously but just build the project differently on every platform.
 We thought of writing the core of the game in C++ in Visual Studio, but there is the problem: How can we test it fast on every platform? How people usually develop multi-platform projects?.
 Also we would really like to hear some recommendations about the source controlling of the whole project. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write your code in C++ in Visual Studio. It is very easy to port your win32 application to Android or iOS with cocos2d-x. There are a lot of tutorials to teach you how to do it. If you create the project with the `python` script[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381634/how-to-install-cocos-2d-x-in-visual-studio-in-window-8-operating-system/19853437#19853437) . You will find there different project in the  folder. After you finish your C++ project, all cocos2d-x Android project needs is the `Classes` and `Resources` folder.

This [link](http://www.einverne.tk/2013/10/cocos2d-x-environment-set-up.html) shows how can you set up cocos2d-x environment both C++ and Android project, but is in Chinese written by me. In brief,for Android project, you need Android SDK and NDK. And follow some step to set up your Android development environment. And you can debug your project.

If you want more details just @me.I am glad to help. PS.I am new in cocos2d-x, I really don't know how other people develop multi-platform projects.